# Using Ajax.ActionLink and ChildActionOnly together in MVC fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

In my view I have  `Ajax.ActionLink`

`@Ajax.ActionLink("Display Information", "Information"}, new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "divCurrentView", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }`)

which calls partial view that replaces the div. Everything works but when I add   `[ChildActionOnly]` to the partial view it never gets executed

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult Information()
```

is there a different approach to use `Ajax.ActionLink` and `[ChildActionOnly]` together?

I want to prevent anyone navigating to the action using URL

Comment: From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.childactiononlyattribute(v=vs.118).aspx): _Any method that is marked with ChildActionOnlyAttribute can be called only with the Action or RenderAction HTML extension methods._ (its purpose is to prevent it being invoked as a result of a user request)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ChildActionOnlyAttribute` can be used only with the HTML extension methods.

The `ChildActionOnly` attribute ensures that an action method can be called only as a child method from within a view.  we tend to use this attribute to prevent the action methods from being invoked as a result of a user request.

In your case,instead of using `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute use `AjaxOnly` as shown :

```
[AjaxOnly]
public PartialViewResult Information()
```

here is how you can make one

```
public class AjaxOnlyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if(!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/error/404");
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {

    }
}
```

and use it like

```
[AjaxOnly]
public PartialViewResult Information()
```

Comment: Works. Where should I store the custom ActionFilterAttribute code? folder? what is the convention? Also in the view I have @Html.Action("DefaultData") that gets executed by default when the view gets rendered. With the change it fails because it is not ajax action and also need this action to be [AjaxOnly] Is it an easy fix? Thanks

Comment: @Ben...just make a folder named `Filters` or `CustomAttributes` in root directory of your project and add a `.cs` file in that folder and add `ajaxonlyattribute` code there and same as `Childactiononly` attribute protects the action if you enter url directly from browser same with `ajaxonly` attribute it will block the requests other then `ajax request`.

Comment: Thanks alot. Any ideas on how to make @Html.Action("DefaultData") to execute on page render?

Comment: @Ben.. Yes then what is the problem on pageload your `@Html.Action` will call `DefaultData` action and data will shown in the view..so what's the problem??

Comment: I have many Ajax.ActionLink. On page load I call '@Html.Action' to load the partial view. The same action user can call using '@Ajax.ActionLink' but now it fails because it is not ajax. Was wondering if it is an easy fix or I will just create duplicate DefaultData action.. call it DefaultData2 and load it on page load and other for ajax request. hopefully my explanation makes sense.

Comment: @Ben... Yes .. yes...now i understand your requirement but unfortunately in my opinion in this case you have to make two actions one with `ChildActionOnly` and other with `AjaxOnly` attributes and in my opinion its a good idea also make one action to serve ajax requests and other for childactions.